# In Swift Sprite Kit is Core Data available?

Tags: ios, core-data, swift, sprite-kit

I have a game I'm creating that has utilizes arrays, lots of them. In order to be more concise in my code and because swift won't compile long arrays (at least for me) I'd like to store my values in a database. Is core data not available in Sprite Kit? If not, what are the alternatives? I did a google search but I didn't have much luck finding anything.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Both SpriteKit and CoreData are (independent) iOS frameworks. What makes you think that you cannot use them both?

Comment: Just that when I created the SpriteKit game it didn't give me the option to use Core Data like if I create a non-game app. I'm not sure how to implement Core Data myself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I ended up doing was creating a new swift project with core data (not a game) and copying the core data logic from the AppDelegate over to my games app delegate. The I created the datamodel by right clicking, new <> and put in the data structure I wanted. This actually worked fine for me and I'm having no issues now. Thanks to all that responded.

Answer (score 2):

It is true that when you create a spritekit project it does not give you the option to use core data. However, it is possible to add the core data framework yourself, as well as creating core data files. There are also other methods for saving scores in games, such as saving to a .plist file, which I currently use for saving high scores in my games.

Comment: Thanks for the info :). I'll try to find how and what to add. I think core data is my best bet since my app is so data intensive.